# how can I get month from date in django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to make a query and return only the month of the year of the date field from my models then compare the return result to the current month of the year.

```
    current_date = datetime.date.today()
    _history = PayrollModel.objects.filter(employee_id_id=employee_id)
    if(_history == None or _history.count() == 0):
        return True
    if(_history != None and _history.count() != 0):
        # entity = _history.get(month_year=current_date)
        for history in _history:
            print(history.employee_id_id)
            if(history.month_year__month != current_date.month and history.month_year.year == current_date.year):
                return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: @AbhinavMathur the month has to come from the models

Comment: how do you mean sir

Comment: Add the `history` model to the question

Answer (score 0):

[Filtering by month](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#month) is a built-in  queryset feature. You don't show your `History` model, so I am writing as if  the relevant date stamp field is called `xdate` (date might read confusingly)

So you need to further filter:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
current_year = today.year
current_month = today.month
_history = _history.filter( xdate__year = current_year, xdate__month = current_month)
for history in _history:
    ...
```

Comment: `class PayrollModel(models.Model):`
    month_year = models.DateField(null=True)`

Comment: this is my model and I want to filter base on employee_id from the listen return I want to get the month_year field and return only the month

Comment: The `month_year` field is a `datetime.date` object (if not None/null), so its month is `some_instance.month_year.month`.

Answer (score 0):

Write the query according the following way-

```
month_wise_sales = Order.objects\
                   .annotate(month=Cast('created_at', DateField()))\
                   .values('month')\
                   .annotate(total_sales=Sum('total_price'))
```

If necessary to use in Django templates then you can use it-

```
{{ monthly_sales.month | date:"M"}}
```